# How to make a background change its position based on the position on the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting to make a website that uses a background that moves based on the position that the curser is on the website. 
I have found this website that gives a visual representation of what I want to do. http://www.alexandrerochet.com/
I just need to know how to make the letters move. I will replace them with images later.

Comment: That website looks like it has a 3d effect going on. If you used three.js or some 3d library then you could have the 3d effect. That is the hard part. Having some function you need to pass a mouse position to relative to the center of the screen is relatively easy. Are you saying you don't have either of those things yet? I wouldn't worry about the mouse part until you have the 3d part done

Comment: OK, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Also if you don't need your result to look so 3D you might have some luck just using css3 and using rotate(). but it would basically be 2D like tilting a piece of paper up/down/left/right when looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try using **parallax.js** to achieve the desired effect.

Demo [site](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/).

Quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/londongrammar/r0g4h0zt/).

```js
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);
parallaxInstance.friction(0.2, 0.2);
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
 background-color: #F9F871;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
.scene {
 top: 30%;
}
.layer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
}
.item {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
}
.item-1 {
 background-color: #FF9671;
 left: 30%;
}
.item-2 {
 background-color: #D65DB1;
 left: 60%;
}
.item-3 {
 background-color: #FF6F91;
 left: 40%;
}
.item-4 {
 background-color: #FFC75F;
 left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="scene" class="scene">
   <div data-depth="0.2" class="layer layer-1">
    <div class="item item-1"></div>
    <div class="item item-2"></div>
   </div>
   <div data-depth="0.6" class="layer layer-2">
    <div class="item item-3"></div>
    <div class="item item-4"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: WOW! This is amazing. Thank you so much for showing me this. It will make my website and future website so much easier to make!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `css properties`.

> Based on Lea Verou's talk

```js
const root = document.documentElement;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
  let x = evt.clientX / innerWidth;
  let y = evt.clientY / innerHeight;

  root.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", x);
  root.style.setProperty("--mouse-y", y);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

:root {
  --mouse-x: .5;
  --mouse-y: .5;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( at calc(var(--mouse-x) * 100%) calc(var(--mouse-y) * 100%), transparent, black);
}
```